# Order Sent Failed with Error #130

Tags: mql4

I'm trying to insert a `takeprofit` and `stoploss` argument in my **`SendOrder()`** function, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Order Sent Failed with Error #130
```

This is my code:

```
extern double takeprofit = 30.0;
extern double stoploss   = 20.0;

stoploss   = NormalizeDouble( stoploss,   5 );                  // SET stop loss
Print( "stoploss", stoploss );

takeprofit = NormalizeDouble( takeprofit, 5 );                  // SET take profit

ticket     = OrderSend( Symbol(),
                        OP_SELL,
                        lotsize,
                        Ask,
                        100,
                        stoploss,
                        takeprofit,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        CLR_NONE
                        );
if (  ticket < 0 ) {
      Print( "Order send failed with error #", GetLastError() );
   }
else  Print( "Order send sucesso!!" );
```

I already checked documentation for the function **`NormalizeDouble()`**, but I'm still getting the error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A ) Fully comply with the MQL4 `OrderSend()` syntax requirements

```
int    anOrderTKT;                                // DECLARE int
double anOrderLotSIZE;                            // DECLARE double
string anOrderCommentSTRING;                      // DECLARE string

anOrderTKT = OrderSend( _Symbol,                  // CPU-glitch, is faster than calling Symbol(),
                        OP_SELL,                  // XTO.Type
                        anOrderLotSIZE,           // XTO.Size       [LT]s
                        Bid,                      // XTO.EntryPRICE { OP_BUY: Ask | OP_SELL: Bid }
                        100,                      // XTO.SLIPPAGE   [PT]s
                        0,                        // XTO.SL_PRICE
                        0,                        // XTO.TP_PRICE,
                        anOrderCommentSTRING,     // XTO.Comment
                        0,                        // XTO.MagNUM#
                        0,                        // XTO.PendingOrderEXPIRE
                        CLR_NONE                  // GUI.MarkerCOLOR
                        );                        // ==> { EMPTY | aTkt# }
```

Your code fails at setting a correct SHORT trade Entry-Price, as it shall read rather **`Bid`**, not `Ask` ( this error is hidden as it is effectively masked-out by a rather cosmic distance of 100 points in a tolerable slippage distance from the said price ).

Your code fails at assigning `int` ( `0` ) in place, where `string` is expected.

### B) Error 130: == "invalid stops"

You shall verify with your Broker a few details:

1. Does their Terms & Conditions allow to **`OrderSend()`** one-stop-instruction, incl, TP & SL, or does the Broker T&C require to first open a trade-position & only after that happens to allow an **`OrderModify()`** instruction to setup TP & SL price-levels?
2. In either case, check your Broker T&C settings for **`STOPLEVEL`** & **`FREEZELEVEL`** distances, within which Broker rejects any TP & SL setup(s) or modification(s) thereof.

---

### C) A good practice is not to assign into `extern` iterator-variables

While this is not a root-cause for your trouble, do get accustomed with an industry best practices, one of which is not to assign any value to a declared **`extern`**. Rather declare your own variable, that you control scope & assignments thereof, but leave `extern`(s) un-touched from your code side.