# Tkinter GUI Layout Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to write a function that makes a `frame` as it's the only argument
and
 adds four buttons in the layout shown below.
( `Button1` and `Button2` are in a red frame and the other two in a yellow frame )

```
  +---------------------------------------+
  |                                       |
  |  [Button1]                            |
  |               [Button3]    [Button4]  |
  |  [Button2]                            |
  |                                       |
  +---------------------------------------+
```

This is just homework. Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk


def pressed():

    print("Button Pressed!")


def create_layout(frame):


    frame1 = frame(frame, bg = "red")
    frame1.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = tk.BOTH)

    b = Button(frame, text='Button1', padx = 20, command=pressed)
    b.pack(pady = 20, padx = 20)
    c = Button(frame, text='Button2', padx = 20, command=pressed)
    c.pack(pady = 20, padx = 20)

    frame2 = frame(frame, bg = "yellow")
    frame2.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = tk.BOTH)

    button3 = tk.Button(frame, text="Button3", command=pressed)
    button3.pack(pady = 20, padx = 20)

    button4 = tk.Button(frame, text="Button4", command=pressed)
    button4.pack(pady = 20, padx = 20)
```

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad as stated. What specific problem are you having? Your code has several errors before you ever get to the problem of laying out your widgets.

Comment: If you can use grid instead of pack, button1 is row 0, column 0.  Button2 is row 2, column 0.  Button3 is row 1, column1.  Button4 is row 1, column 2.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with your code. The key to doing widget layout is to be methodical, and to not try to solve every problem at once.

My recommendation is to first focus on getting your red and yellow frames working, and nothing else. Write just enough code to get those to appear where you want them, and to have proper behavior when you resize the window. You've made a good choice using `pack`, as it's perfectly suited for the job of arranging widgets left-to right or top-to-bottom.

Once you have that working, then you can focus on the buttons. Pick one frame or the other, and focus on just getting the buttons to work in one frame. Make sure that widgets inside that frame use that frame as its parent.

Finally, work on the remaining frame, doing the exact same thing again. In all cases, My advice is to always be explicit and use the `side` attribute. While it's OK to rely on defaults, when learning it's good to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk


def pressed():
    """
    Button callback function (command).

    You may alter what this function does if you wish, but you must not rename
    or delete it.

    """
    print("Button Pressed!")


def create_layout(frame: tk.Frame) -> None:
    """
    Add four buttons to the frame in the given formt.

    Both buttons should have the callback (command) pressed, and they should
    have the labels "Button1" through "Button4".

    The layout in the frame after running this function will be:
      +---------------------------------------+
      |                                       |
      |  [Button1]                            |
      |               [Button3]    [Button4]  |
      |  [Button2]                            |
      |                                       |
      +---------------------------------------+

    Parameters:
        frame (tk.Frame): The frame to create the two buttons in.

    """
    
    frame1 = tk.Frame(frame, bg="red")
    frame1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)
    frame.config(bg='yellow')
    
    button1 = tk.Button(frame1, text="Button1", command=pressed)
    button1.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=1)

    button2 = tk.Button(frame1, text="Button2", command=pressed)
    button2.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=1)

    button3 = tk.Button(frame, text="Button3", command=pressed)
    button3.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=1)

    button4 = tk.Button(frame, text="Button4", command=pressed)
    button4.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=1)
```

Answer (score -2):

### GUI Layout Composition and Auto-scaling requirements decide.

Tkinter has many building-blocks ( widget, frame, canvas ) and several so called geometry managers **`{ .pack() | .grid() | .place() }`** to "put parts  together", into some bigger picture, with some rationale behind.

Each of these named geometry managers helps to achieve a common behaviour of the Tkinter - auto-scaling ( if requied ) of the whole GUI composition. Each one is well-equipped for some particular type of layout composition. There is not a *universal master-of-all-masters* or "Jack-of-all-trades", but each one has it's own strengths suitable for a particular layout model.

GUI layout needs are very different and Tkinter methods help one achieve the desired look-and-feel model and allow to (almost) forget about many internal relations and cross-dependencies between individual composition element's resulting position, edges, sizing and scaling.

```
Where .pack() or .grid() may help:

 +--<Frame>-frame-----------------------------------------------------+
 |                                                                    |
 |   +-<Frame>-aYelFrame----------+  +-<Frame>-aRedFrame----------+   |
 |   |         side = tk.LEFT     |  |         side = tk.RIGHT    |   |
 |   |         fill = tk.BOTH     |  |         fill = tk.BOTH     |   |
 |   |  +----------------------+  |  |  +----------++----------+  |   |
 |   |  [                      ]  |  |  [          ][          ]  |   |
 |   |  [                      ]  |  |  [          ][          ]  |   |
 |   |  [                      ]  |  |  [          ][          ]  |   |
 |   |  [                      ]  |  |  [          ][          ]  |   |
 |   |  [                      ]  |  |  [          ][          ]  |   |
 |   |  [                      ]  |  |  [          ][          ]  |   |
 |   |  +-<Button>-------------+  |  |  [          ][          ]  |   |
 |   |  +----------------------+  |  |  [          ][          ]  |   |
 |   |  [                      ]  |  |  [          ][          ]  |   |
 |   |  [                      ]  |  |  [          ][          ]  |   |
 |   |  [                      ]  |  |  [          ][          ]  |   |
 |   |  [                      ]  |  |  [          ][          ]  |   |
 |   |  [                      ]  |  |  [          ][          ]  |   |
 |   |  [                      ]  |  |  [          ][          ]  |   |
 |   |  +-<Button>-------------+  |  |  +-<Button>-++-<Button>-+  |   |
 |   |                            |  |                            |   |
 |   +----------------------------+  +----------------------------+   |
 |                                                                    |
 +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Layout strategy decides on which of the available methods are more or less handy.

You **could** use another Tkinter geometry manager method, instead of `.pack()`, e.g. **`.place()`**:

```
aSampleButton = tk.Button( aRedFrame, text   = "aSampleButton", ... )
aSampleButton.place(                  x      =   0,  # in pixels - a Widget x position,
                                      y      =   0,  # in pixels - a Widget y position,
                                      width  = 100,  # in pixels - a Widget absolute width,
                                      height =  15,  # in pixels - a Widget absolute height
)
```

This way you retain the freedom to design the UI within `Frame` fully under your control.

```
 Where .place() may help to design a UI,
                where arranging
                widgets left-to right / top-to-bottom is not the case,
                with a complete down-to-pixel layout control
                that is warmly welcome in cases,
                where a bitmap layer has to be met pixel-by-pixel,
                like if you need to place controls ( buttons et al )
                onto a bitmap picture of an instrument ( an Oscilloscope, Sonar )
                and mediate interactions between GUI and device / process

 +--<Frame>-frame-----------------------------------------------------+
 |                                   +-<Frame>-aRedFrame----------+   |
 |                                   |                            |   |
 |                                   |                            |   |
 |   +-<Frame>-aYelFrame----------+  |                            |   |
 |   | +-------------+            |  |                            |   |
 |   | [             ]            |  |                            |   |
 |   | [             ]            |  |                            |   |
 |   | [             ]            |  |                            |   |
 |   | [             ]            |  |                            |   |
 |   | [             ]            |  |                            |   |
 |   | [             ]            |  |                            |   |
 |   | +-<Button>----+            |  |+----------+                |   |
 |   |                            |  |[          ]    +----------+|   |
 |   |                            |  |+-<Button>-+    [          ]|   |
 |   |                            |  |                +-<Button>-+|   |
 |   |                            |  |                            |   |
 |   |       +-------------------+|  |                            |   |
 |   |       [                   ]|  |                            |   |
 |   |       +-<Button>----------+|  |                            |   |
 |   |                            |  |                            |   |
 |   |                            |  +----------------------------+   |
 |   |                            |                                   |
 |   +----------------------------+                                   |  
 |                                                                    |
 +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

<sub>**Nota bene:** while there are several layout managers available, it is fair to state and also to stick to such a practice, to **avoid using more than one geometry manager within the same parent-framing**. Where necessary, one may rather redesign the parent-child relations so as to keep all widgets related to the same parent-framing to use the same layout geometry manager method ( all `.pack()` or all `.place()`, but do not mix them ).</sub>

<sup>This text is intended for users who start building their understanding of `Tkinter` from about an entry-level practice with `Tkinter` code. Hawkish practiotioners will for sure have many higher-level insights and countless pieces of hands-on experience. The answer does not have an ambition to provide a code, but was served in a belief that bringing a bit of light onto driving principles may help users grasp concepts, that are not so straigthforward visible from syntax-oriented documentation ( and might be hard to derive from a reverse-engineering of code-samples from other (semi-)finalised code-snippets with possibly incompatible layout strategy motivations )</sup>

Comment: Yes, @jonsharpe. If your objection is about a non-PEP8, then this was intentional. StackOverflow aims at **helping understanding how & why** for people, that typically do not participate in teams who perform global code-base maintentace and shared co-development. PEP-8 motivation is other.

Comment: Then you could at least *mention that* in your answer. PEP-8's motivation (as with any style guide) is to make code more consistent and therefore easier to read, parse and understand; it's not clear why you think that wouldn't apply here, or how your formatting aids understanding at all.

Comment: Yes, typically I put a note about this in [edit] summary, that non-PEP8 format was used to help faster Task Solution focus. You are right

Comment: Thank you. Follow-up question: how exactly does unconventional formatting *"help faster Task Solution focus"*?

Comment: `place`, while usable, rarely is the best choice. There's no reason not to use `grid` or `pack` in this situation, either of which can give the desired result with less work.

Comment: @user3666197: You didn't answer the question, and likely caused more confusion than clarity. For one, the user isn't using classes, so the use of `self` will likely be confusing. Also, their code has no `Button0`1` object, so it will be hard  or impossible to relate your answer to their code. Third, you don't actually address the problem of laying out four widgets in two frames, you only show how to lay out one widget in one frame.  And even if `place` were the right or reasonable choice, you don't explain why you recommend it. Your answer comes across more as a "shot in the dark" guess.

Comment: On class objection, yes, you are right, Bryan. On providing complete solution objection, yes, you are right, Bryan. On derived objection of not making both Frames and Button widgets layout strategy proposal / concrete geometry solution, yes, you are right, Bryan. Thanks for your inputs for my further way how to help people.

Comment: @user3666197 perhaps you should be a little less passive-aggressive when given feedback? Then maybe you wouldn't have to complain about moderation on your user profile.

Comment: **Follow-up answer** if interested in how, check >>> http://stackoverflow.com/q/26333893/3666197 and similar posts, that reflect life-long experience, that for Domain-specific knowledge ( for the sake of a steeper learning curve ), the syntax per-se is focused on compile-phase processing optionally accompanied with a set of rules ( a priori postulated ), and as such does not spend a dime of attention on anything beyond that, thus leaving if not blurring the idea behind ( why the code, as such, has been created ) **which is typically the key part** of one's own ( *not yours* ) learning process.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters With all due respect, another consorship deletion does not help improve the Community Experience and "*indirectly legitimates aggresive attacks observed from other members*". Hiding such patologies only empowers attackers. I would appreciate your decision to roll-back the deleted manifesto as its content **is important for preventing bullying and mobbying**. "*Hiding*" such experience -- in whatever name it was done -- just makes more space for attackers, which is undoubtedly a poor service, **not a help** to cultivate a respect-full community relations here.

Comment: @user3666197: again, this is something you can take to [meta] if you want to discuss this. I'm not censoring, I'm editing for clarity.

Comment: @user3666197: answer posts are for *the solution to the question*, they are not a soapbox for issues about Stack Overflow itself. That's what your profile is for, and what we have Meta for.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not willing to "take something somewhere else". I believe in what has been stated above about a proper care to avoid aggresive habits repeating to appear here, not in silence somewhere else. The Community reads and senses the attacks as they appear here, if Policy Supervisors allow. It is not my fault to notwithstand with the observed practice of attacks.

Comment: That's not how this site works, sorry. I've now locked this post, sorry, but them's the rules here.